# How to hide options in drop down in sharepoint search 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, people-search

I want to hide EveryThing and Conversations in the drop down,can any one please help on this.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can choose to only hide some of them, as the setting for removing them is showing all or none.

I always hide them and let the users refine their search in the search center.

As a site collection administrator, navigate to site settings > under site collection administration > search settings. You have to deselect "Use the same results page settings as my parent." and send your query to a custom result page. ( Your search center site collection. )

Watch the URL's needed carefully.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to Site Settings then Search Settings and remove the options you no longer want.

[image]

Comment: No It is not working when we do like this.